# How to use Viber simultanously on two phones but same account

Tags: accounts, viber-messenger

Is there a way to use synchronized Viber installs on multiple (android) phones?

I know that Viber does not support simultaneous usage of the same account on two phones. Yet I can think of workarounds: I can install Linux on an android phone, and install Viber for Linux. Or remotely control a PC or tablet where Viber is installed. Anybody came up will a less tedious solution?